# How do I resize the Vue JS v-timeline dividers on a horizontal timeline?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, timeline

I have a Vue JS 3 project where I am using the v-timeline component.  I have a table that has monthly columns, each column has it's own timeline.  What I would like to do is set the column width to a specific width, then have the dividers automatically resize depending on how many items are in it, or just hard code the width of the dividers between the dots.

Current code for each timeline in each column:

```
<td class="timeline" style="border-left: none; border-right: none; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; font-size: 11px ">
    <v-timeline direction="horizontal" side="start">
        <v-timeline-item v-for="i in item.month3"
                         :key="i.dispDate" dot-color="black" :icon="i.iconOpenClose">
            <template v-slot:opposite>
                <v-chip variant="text">
                    <div v-if="i.id === '123456'">
                        <span class="highlightText"> {{ i.dispDate }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div v-else>
                        {{ i.dispDate }}
                    </div>
                </v-chip>
            </template>
            <div v-if="i.actId === '123456'">
                <span class="highlightText"><div class="diagonal-text">{{ i.actDescr }}</div></span>
            </div>
            <div v-else>
                <div class="diagonal-text">{{ i.actDescr }}</div>
            </div>
        </v-timeline-item>
    </v-timeline>
</td>
```

We did try to use the  tag, my colleague said she tried to implement it around the  compoment, but when I tried it,it didn't work at all.  It just messed up how the timelines showed in each column (columns didn't resize and timelines overlapped) and the timeline divider widths didn't end up resizing.

I did use the following code which worked to resize the dividers, it just set the dividers to a hardcoded width, but then my v-slot:opposite items disappeared.  Here is the code for that:

```
<td class="timeline" style="border-left: none; border-right: none; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; font-size: 11px ">
    <v-timeline direction="horizontal" side="start">
        <v-timeline-item v-for="i in item.milestonesMonthPlusThree"
                         :key="i.dispDate" dot-color="black" :icon="i.iconOpenClose">
            <template v-slot:opposite>
                <v-chip variant="text">
                    <div v-if="i.actId === '11079'">
                        <span class="highlightText"> {{ i.dispDate }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div v-else>
                        {{ i.dispDate }}
                    </div>
                </v-chip>
            </template>
            <v-container style="width: 10px">
                <div v-if="i.actId === '11079'">
                    <span class="highlightText"><div class="diagonal-text">{{ i.actDescr }}</div></span>
                </div>
                <div v-else>
                    <div class="diagonal-text">{{ i.actDescr }}</div>
                </div>
            </v-container>
        </v-timeline-item>
    </v-timeline>
</td>
```

I've been sitting on this for a week now and can't find any help on the internet.  Please help!